# How can I get the start of the calendar day from a DateTime object?

Tags: powershell, datetime

I'm trying to filter files older than a certain day, based on the day of the newest file in the directory.

I can get the `LastWriteTime`, which seems to be an exact time of, say `7/24/2016  10:48 AM` for some file.

How can I strip the `10:48 AM` part out of the object so I can compare against `7/24/2016 12:00 AM` instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to retrieve a new [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.aspx) value of midnight on the same date:

```
> $file.LastWriteTime

Sunday, July 24, 2016 10:48:00 AM


> $file.LastWriteTime.Date

Sunday, July 24, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LastWriteTime` property of the `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and `System.IO.FileInfo` instances returned by `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Item` returns an instance of type [`System.DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.DateTime.aspx).
(Verify with: `(Get-Item \).LastWriteTime.GetType().FullName`)

`System.DateTime` represents a point in time (date + time), but has a [`.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) property, which returns another `System.DateTime` instance with the time-of-day portion set to *midnight* at the *start* of the input date, effectively representing a date only.

Compare

```
(Get-ChildItem \).LastWriteTime
```

to

```
(Get-ChildItem \).LastWriteTime.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$thing.LastWriteTime.Day    # e.g. 10, (10th day of the month)

$thing.LastWriteTime.DayOfWeek   # e.g. Wednesday
```

Comment: The title of the question is misleading.  Based on their last sentence the author wants not the day of the week or day of the month but the date.

Comment: @BACON sorry, didn't know how to word it otherwise. Should I have said "Date" instead?

Comment: @guineawheek When I initially saw the question I, too, thought you were looking for the `DayOfWeek` property.  Yes, in the .NET world (if not in general), I would use "date" to refer to "a combination of year, month, and day".  Although, if you didn't know about the `Date` property you might not have known to call it that.  No problem, though; sometimes the answer helps to word the question.

Comment: @guineawheek: Perhaps "date only" or "start of the calendar day" or "date without time component"?

Comment: @guineawheek: P.S.: While the _body_ of your question was perfectly clear, the _title_ is what caused confusion, illustrating the importance of question titles.

Comment: Edited. Sorry for the confusion.